# ElasticSearch sort array size incoherent results

Tags: arrays, sorting, elasticsearch

I am trying to sort by array size in ElasticSearch 7.1.

I indexed the following data without creating any custom mapping:

```json
{
  "myarray": [{
    "field": {
      "value": "test"
    }
  }]
}
```

When I look at the mapping, it is giving me:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "myarray": {
      "properties": {
        "field": {
          "properties": {
            "value": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to query the index and sort by the highest number of elements in `myarray`. I have tried doing:

```json
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc",
        "script": "doc.containsKey('myarray.field.value') ? doc['myarray.field.value'].values.size() : 0"
    }
  }
}
```

which gives me an error like `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default.[...] Alternatively use a keyword field instead`. So I try with

```json
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc",
        "script": "doc.containsKey('myarray.field.value.keyword') ? doc['myarray.field.value.keyword'].values.size() : 0"
    }
  }
}
```

which gives me the error `Illegal list shortcut value [values].`. So then I tried with (removing the `values` keyword):

```json
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc",
        "script": "doc.containsKey('myarray.field.value.keyword') ? doc['myarray.field.value.keyword'].size() : 0"
    }
  }
}
```

and it works, however I have some results that are sorted nicely and suddenly an element that should be at the top appears in the middle.
Is that because it is sorting by the length of the `value` as a string and not the length of `myarray`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because **text** type mapping does not provide sorting, to add sorting you must map the array field with **keyword** type.
For more info and syntax please refer this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html

Comment: But using `myarray.field.value.keyword` should work then, no? since the mapping is of `"type": "keyword"`

Comment: Try doing this only ```doc['myarray'].values.size()```

Comment: This gives error `No field found for [myarray] in mapping with types []`

Comment: ```"script": "doc['myarray'].values.size()"``` , just this?, I guess I might need to look into syntax